# Another jQuery Ajax Request Error

Tags: php, html, jquery

Sorry for asking such a question again. I've been looking for a solution for hours but nobody could help me. So maybe someone here knows what the problem is.
I was writing a login form, which sends entered data to an PHP script on the server. The PHP script should do the work. All connections are secured so sending clear passwords is no problem.

My login form (login.php) looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="/layout/main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/models/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function submitLogin() {

    $.post("login_process.php", { username: "TEST" },
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });

     }

    </script>
    <title>Login</title>



    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="loginwrapper">
        <div id="content">

            <div id="main">

            <h1>Login</h1>


            <div id="errors">

            </div>     


                <div id="regbox">
                    <form name="newUser" onsubmit="submitLogin()" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                         <label>Password:</label>
                         <input type="password" name="password" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit" />
                    </p>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and my process file (login_process.php) looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode("OK");
exit;
?>
```

I'm distressed. Why doesn't it show a message saying "OK" ? :(

Comment: Are `login.php` and `login_process.php` in the same directory? Also, is the issue that the alert is firing but you're not seeing data, or that the alert isn't firing at all?

Comment: they are in the same directory. Firebug's saying it sends data, but it doesn't receive...

Comment: nope, firebug tells me that there is an error

Comment: well, that's a good thing. What is the error that Firebug reports?

Comment: it just says that there is no response....

Comment: Ok, then most likely there is an error occurring on the server-side. Do you have error logging turned on in php.ini? If so, check your log to see if there are any errors relevant to your login_process requests. The most likely issue is that you'll get a 'Headers already sent' error from PHP at the line # of your `header` function call.

Comment: no it doesn't give me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line gives you an error:

```
data: "user="&document.forms["newUser"]["username"].value&"&password="&document.forms["newUser"]["password"].value,
```

Its fairly simple, `&` is a BOOLEAN AND operator in JavaScript. Use the `+` operator instead for string concatenation.

## Edit 1

The code appears to work perfectly OK on my system with one minor change:

```
onsubmit="submitLogin(); return false;"
```

Comment: Try removing `header` in the server side script. Also, can you check (using FireBug Net inspector) what is being posted to the server?

Comment: the sending-header: Host localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0
Accept */*
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection keep-alive
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
Referer https://localhost/login.php
Content-Length 13
Cookie PHPSESSID=ef5be977b624073e568545289f5acb7c

Comment: Aha... ok... at least do you get `200 OK` in the response? And also, what happens when you open login_process.php page directly in the browser? Do you see `"OK"`?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Add `&callback=?` at the end of data for .ajax() and modify login_process.php so:

   header('Content-type: application/json');

   $return['msg'] = "OK";

   echo $_POST['callback']."('".json_encode($return)."');";

   exit;

When running the success functions "name" is inserted in place of ? in the callback=?. And what you are essentially doing in your php script is "calling" this success function.

1. Use XMLHttpRequest so:

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   var data = new FormData();

   data.append("msg", "I am now testing you");

   data.append("data", "blahblahblah");

   xhr.open('POST', 'login_process.php', true);

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

   ```
   if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)

       alert("YAY!");
   ```

   }

   xhr.send(data);

Comment: what do you mean by adding callback at the end of .ajax?

Comment: I meant add `&callback=?` to the end of _data:_ in .ajax()

Comment: What do you mean manually? Adding the callback? Well then, have you tried using XMLHttpRequest?